# Map similar like clusters in two different cluster sets

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, clustering

I have two sets of clusters (Cluster_set_1 and Cluster_set_2) obtained by analysing two different sets of news paper articles.

A cluster includes word/word phrases as given in the examples below.

```
C1 in Cluster_set_1: Energy, Fuel, Oil, Mining
C2 in Cluster_set_1: school, education, students, schools, million, read
...
...
etc.

C1 in Cluster_set_2: Gas, oil, pipeline
C2 in Cluster_set_2: program, business, management,information, reports
...
...
etc.
```

Now I want to find clusters in the two cluster sets that are similar/related by considering the word/word phrases in the cluster as given in the example below.

```
Example: 
Cluster of 'Energy, Fuel, Oil, Mining' in Cluster_set_1 is mostly similar/related to 
Cluster of 'Gas, oil, pipeline' in Cluster_set_2

Reason: Because they both includes word/word phrases related to Energy
```

Since, I am dealing with two separate sets of clusters, what would be a suitable approach that I can use to connect the clusters in the two different sets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine two sets of clusters](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22324/combine-two-sets-of-clusters)

Comment: No, I am interested in knowing without LDA topics

Answer (score 3):

I would investigate a [soft clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_clustering) approach using [HDBSCAN clustering](http://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/soft_clustering_explanation.html). 
Some reading on text clustering [here](https://recast.ai/blog/introduction-text-clustering/), which includes discussion on clustering with DBSCAN, HDBSCAN's non-hierarchical precursor