# What is Hellinger Distance and when to use it?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining, distance

I am interested in knowing what really happens in  Hellinger Distance (in simple terms). Furthermore, I am also interested in knowing what are types of problems that we can use  Hellinger Distance? What are the benefits of using  Hellinger Distance?

Comment: The Hellinger distance is a probabilistic analog of the Euclidean distance. A salient property is its symmetry, as a metric. Such mathematical properties are useful if you are writing a paper and you need a distance function that possesses certain properties to make your proof possible. In application, someone might discover that one metric produces nicer or better results than another for a certain task; e.g., the [Wasserstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) is all the rage in [generative adversarial networks](https://www.quora.com/What-is-new-with-Wasserstein-GAN)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I came across this question, which is quite similar to the question I have now. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22324/combine-two-sets-of-clusters Please let me know, why the answer says Hellinger Distance is suitable?

Comment: Probably to [visualize](https://blakeboswell.github.io/2016/gensim-hellinger/) the topics in a metric space. Another nice property is that the Hellinger distance is finite for distributions with different support. It is good that you are asking these questions. I suggest trying different metrics for yourself and observing the results.

Comment: Thanks. its a good link. helps a lot. But is Hellinger distance only limited to topics derived from Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) as mentioned in the link?

Comment: No, it has no inherent connection to LDA.

Comment: Thanks. The points you mentioned helped a lot to understand.

Comment: Have you seen the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance)?

Comment: @Emre Please let me know if you know an answer for this https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22828/clustering-with-cosine-similarity

Answer (score 12):

[Hellinger distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance) is a metric to measure the difference between two probability distributions. It is the probabilistic analog of [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).

Given two probability distributions, $P$ and $Q$, Hellinger distance is defined as:

$$h(P,Q) = \frac1{\sqrt2}\cdot \|\sqrt{P}-\sqrt{Q}\|_2$$

It is useful when quantifying the difference between two probability distributions. For example, if you estimate a distribution for users and non-users of a service. If the Hellinger distance is small between those groups for some features, then those features are not statistically useful for segmentation.

Comment: (also for @Emre) where does the claim that hellinger distance is the probabilistic analog of euclidean distance comes from? why is that?